# How to correctly require jsPlumb in a node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, jsplumb

Since jsPlumb is not available in npm I have to add it manualy to my codebase. If I download it, put it in `./libraries/dom.jsPlumb-1.7.5.js` and do a

```
var plumb = require('./libraries/dom.jsPlumb-1.7.5.js')
```

in my JavaScript, I get an error message in my console during application Startup:

```
Can't set property "jsBezier" of an undefined or nullpointer reference
File dom.jsPlumb-1.7.5.js', line: 3, col: 8232
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you try without the .js extension?

Comment: Couldn't find any docs about jsPlumb with nodejs. I'm not sure if jsPlumb is for backend!

Comment: it is not - that is why I am asking on how to include it anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for that and posted it on the Issues Page of jsPlumb on github. See https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/issues/399